# UWP app displays nothing but a blank screen, no elements?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I created a UWP app for the first time. Well adding a xaml element nothing shows up.The program starts black i think from being in dark mode. Anyway i changed background to white.
nothing else has been changed, i didnt mess with the other files just yet. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPwbe.png) Any clues would be great thanks.

Tried doing the same thing in wpf and works but not UWP.
changed VS light and dark mode which changes the background color of the app
tried adding images and other xaml elements
Tried looking it up like "UWP isnt showing xaml elements. but only blank screen." couldnt find anything.

Comment: Could you please run your app to see if the button will show when running? If it is, them this might be just a display issue of the Xaml designer tool.

Comment: Yeah when I run the application it just shows a blank screen no xaml elements. Im not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: I tired the code based on the image, but it works correctly on my side. What about give the button a background color?

Comment: Have you checked this yet?